# is it possible to change data provider of flex chart from a seperate ActionScript class?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

Im trying to change flex chart data provider from seperate action script class? is it possible. i did not find any method to do that. any ideas guys ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. For that you need to have a reference to dataprovider of chart and it should be bindable. It means when you update dataProvider you view also will be update ( chart in this case ). 
If it doesn't help you, I would see your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  A nice clean way is to have a custom event dispatcher facade:

```
package com.app.facades
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    [Event(name="showDataInGrid"   , type="com.app.events.GridEvent")]
    public class GridFacade extends EventDispatcher
    {
        private static var _instance:GridFacade;

        public function GridFacade(lock:SingletonLock, target:IEventDispatcher=null) {
            super(target);
            if(!(lock is SingletonLock)) {
                throw(new Error("GridFacade is a singleton, please do not make foreign instances of it"));
            }
        }

        public static function getInstance():GridFacade {
            if(!_instance) {
                _instance = new GridFacade(new SingletonLock());
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
class SingletonLock{}
```

create a dispatchable event like so:

```
package com.app.events {

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

    public class DispatchableEvent extends Event implements IDispatchableEvent {
        protected var _dispatcher:IEventDispatcher;

        public function DispatchableEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }

        public function dispatch():void
        {
            _dispatcher.dispatchEvent(this);
        }
    }
}
```

then have a custom GridEvent like so:

```
package com.app.events {
    public class GridEvent extends DispatchableEvent {
        public static const SHOW_DATA_IN_GRID:String = "showDataInGrid";
        public var data:Object;
        public function GridEvent(type:String, 
                                  data:ArrayCollection = null, 
                                  bubbles:Boolean=false, 
                                  cancelable:Boolean=false) {
            super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
            _dispatcher = GridFacade.getInstance();
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

then listen for the showDataInGrid event in the scope of your grid component:

```
...
GridFacade.getInstance().addEventListener(GridEvent.SHOW_DATA_IN_GRID, onShowDataInGrid);
...

protected function onShowDataInGrid(event:GridEvent):void {
    myGrid.dataProvider = event.data;
    // refresh the collection so that the component will display the new data
    event.data.refresh();
    // remember to reset any data specific stuff you may have set in the grid component before doing this.
}
```

to actually change the data, in any class you wish do the following:

```
(new GridEvent(
    GridEvent.SHOW_DATA_IN_GRID,
    someCollectionToShowInTheGrid,
)).dispatch();
```

And watch the magic!  :)

good luck!